# Non-commutative unitary rings

Tags: ring-theory

How can I show that there are no non-commutative unitary rings of order $n$ with $1 \leq n \leq 7$ and that there exists a non-commutative unitary ring of order 8?

I could use any help, because we did not treat this during the lectures yet

Comment: Not field theory, not ring theory.

Comment: There is only one abelian group of each of the orders you have from $1$ through $7$, and you should be able to prove that the multiplication is then forced and is commutative; For $n=8$, just produce an example!

Comment: I'm voting to close, but I will give hints: 1)  search this site for answers. They're already there.  2) upper triangular matrix ring.